# TYPO3 Flux - getting content of grid returns nothing

Tags: typo3, flux, fluid

I have a flux-grid that looks like this:

```
<flux:grid>
    <flux:grid.row>
        <flux:grid.column name="content" label="Content"/>
    </flux:grid.row>
</flux:grid>
```

It's a wrapper for other content-elements (namely elements of a slider).

Now I need to wrap each of the elements in a `<li>`-Tag.

So I thought I get the content as an array and render it in an each-loop.

```
<flux:content.render area="content" as="slides" render="1" />
```

I thought I'd have the elements in a variable called `slides` now. But that doesn't seem to be the case. When I use `<f:debug>{slides}</f:debug>` I get just an empty variable...

Thus, this fails:

```
<f:for each="{slides}" as="slide">
    <f:debug>{slide}</f:debug>
</f:for>
```

Just outputting the content like this works, though:

```
<flux:content.render area="content"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

[Edit]

I'm one step further...

```
<v:variable.set name="contentElements" value="{flux:content.get(area:'content',  render:'FALSE')}" />
```

Does indeed return an array with the elements.

But when I try to render the elements, they're empty:

```
<f:for each="{contentElements}" as="contentElement">
    UID: {contentElement.uid}<br />
    <v:content.render contentUids="{0:contentElement.uid}" />
</f:for>
```

the UID is correctly outputted - the v:content.render fails

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I was just using an old Vhs-Version.

Saw in the Extensions that it had an update (to 4.3.3) and now it's working...